# Links, HTMLs on Stack Overflow's About Me column

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

How do we post links on "About Me" Stack Overflow? So far, I've tried html, [name][link] format, name format, [name][link_index] format, but seems like it didn't work.. Any ideas?

Here is what I write on my bio:

```
You can contact me on Twitter ([@akhyarkamili][1]), or just email me. 

   [1]: (http:/twitter.com/akhyarkamili)
```

But still, you can see in my profile that it's not a link. On answers, questions, chats and comments it does though.

Comment: Have you read [the editing help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? There is no different between post section and "About Me" section.

Comment: Have you read my attempts? Yeah of course i know that.

Comment: It is.. In the example: `Here's a reference-style link to [Google][1].
`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I edited your profile here. Once I made the following change, your link shows up.

Your URL was not written correctly. You had:

```
http:/twitter...
```

Instead of:

```
http://twitter...
```

So the code did not recognize what you typed as a url.

Comment: Gosh, couldn't believe i missed that. Pretty embarassing :$ Thanks!!

Comment: @aIKid hehe... I have made *much worse* goofs myself!

Answer (score 3):

Addition to [@Andrew's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202932/187824), you don't need to add brackets in the links at bottom:

Try this:

```
You can contact me on Twitter ([@akhyarkamili][1]), or just email me. 

   [1]: http://twitter.com/akhyarkamili
```

instead of

```
You can contact me on Twitter ([@akhyarkamili][1]), or just email me. 

   [1]: (http:/twitter.com/akhyarkamili)
   -----^------------------------------^---Remove these brackets
```